# Using the Generic Type

Tags: java

My Instructor for my Data structures class has told me that there is a better way to implement using a Generic Data type in this method instead of casting everything to E. I am unable to figure out how this better way is implemented or exactly what she means. I know this method I wrote works but if there is a better way I would like to know.

```
public class GenericSortedArrayBag<E extends Comparable> implements Cloneable,Iterable<E> {
    public int numPresents;
    public int maxPresents;
    private Object[] data;
public void delete(E k) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0; i <numPresents; i++) {
        if(((E)data[i]).equals(k)) {
            found = true;   
            }
        if(found && i<numPresents - 1) {
            data[i] = data[i+1];
        }
        else if(found) {
            data[i] = null;
        }
    }
    numPresents--;
}
```

Comment: The only cast I see in your code is actually unnecessary—just do `data[i].equals(k)`. Also, your class should probably use `<E extends Comparable<E>>` instead of `<E extends Comparable>`.

Comment: Are you only supposed to modify the method or also other parts of the class?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
private Object[] data;
```

you can use

```
private E[] data;
```

That way you save the cast

```
if((data[i]).equals(k))
```